# Move Data between different Databases

Tags: mysql, migration, hsqldb

i would like to know if there is any kind of tool to move data from one database to another. In my case i'm trying to move data from hsqldb to mysql.
I've already tried with mysql workbench, but it doesn't support hsqldb.

I think the worst case would be to export data into sql-files, modify these and try to import them in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was SQL-Workbench, which can be used to copy/sync data between databases. You can execute sql-Files in the cli which makes it easy to run remote.
To copy/move/snyc/whatever your data, just use WbCopy.

example:

`WbCopy -sourceConnection='username=SA,url=jdbc:hsqldb:/db/myDb' 
-targetConnection='username=root,url=jdbc:mysql://someIp:3306/myDB' 
-targetTable=SOMETABLE -sourceTable=SOMETABLE -ignoreIdentityColumns=false 
-mode=insert,update -keyColumns=ID -deleteTarget=false -continueOnError=false;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/migrating-from-hsqldb-to-mysql-658737210.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Kind of, MySQL Migration Toolkit does not exist anymore and has been replaced by MySQL Workbench. Sadly it does not support hsqldb (as far as i understood)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few cross-platform tools to move data between different database. These include [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). See this page for a list of useful utilities http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlUsing.html